# how to prevent stacking function callbacks while exiting a screen react/react-native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-navigation

I have a local state `selectedProducts` holding a number representing the number of products the client has selected, while exiting the screen I want to update the number in redux so it can be viewed in the cart on a different screen.

but every time my local `selectedProducts` updates it stacks another function call on `beforeRemove` event

I know this is a noob problem but I've spent hours trying to find a solution to this problem and advice would be very helpful :)

```
    useEffect(()=>{
     navigation.addListener('beforeRemove', () => {
     console.log('check this', selectedProducts);
     if (!selectedProducts) {
      return;
     }
     dispatch(addToCartMultipleQty(selectedProducts));
     });
    },[selectedProducts])
```

selectedProducts is a number state whose initial value is null and on a button click event its value is either incremented or decremented by 1, if its previous value is null then its value is set to 1

**Note:** I just want to update selectedProducts state's latest value only once in redux when the screen is about to be exited/unmonted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
useEffect(()=>{
  navigation.addListener('beforeRemove', () => {
    console.log('check this', selectedProducts);
    if (!selectedProducts) {
      return;
    }
    dispatch(addToCartMultipleQty(selectedProducts));
  });  
  return () => {
    navigation.removeListener('beforeRemove');
  }
}, [selectedProducts])
```

Answer (score 0):

Add that in return at the end of `useEffect` it will work as `componentWillUnmount` in functional component

```js
useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
        // Anything in here is fired on component unmount.
    }
}, [])
```

Edit: In Your case

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('check this', selectedProducts);
    if (!selectedProducts) {
      return;
    }
    return () => {
      // Anything in here is fired on component unmount.
      if (selectedProducts) {
        dispatch(addToCartMultipleQty(selectedProducts));
      }
    };
  }, [selectedProducts]);
```

Comment: it updates with the initial value of selectedProducts state

Comment: check edit for your case

Comment: hey thanks for the feedback, I've tried it and now it calls dispatch every time the selectedProducts is changed, I want it to run only once when the screen is being exited the main goal here is to make the UI performant by cutting down update calls to redux

Comment: in that case just remove selectedProducts dependency then it will only call when screen is unmounted

Comment: then it will update using the initial value of selectedProducts state which is null, I need it to update with the latest value of selectedProducts state

Comment: there is no details about what selectedProducts is. is it state, or its coming from redux or variable? because you are not updating selectedProducts with useEffect so it should not matter

Comment: selectedProducts is a number state whose initial value is null and on a button click event its value is either incremented or decremented by 1, if its previous value is null then its value is set to 1

I just want to update selectedProducts state's latest value only once in redux when the screen is about to be exited/unmonted

Comment: then return should work because it has nothing to do with dependency array and will take the value stored in state at the time of its invocation

Comment: no, the function is invoked with the initial value of selectedProducts, my assumption is useEffect hook with no dependency creates the callback object with the initial value and stores it in memory, and since it is not listening on any state updates it never updates the callback object
when the component is unmounted it just takes the old outdated object and invokes it

Comment: useEffect does not store values

Comment: I might be wrong but still, it only invokes the callback using the initial value of the selectedProducts state

Comment: it might be possible that your state is not updating at all

Comment: it's updating if I add selectedProducts as a dependency it works as expected but updates redux every time the state is changed